# Image isn't drawn after canvas is cleared (html5 canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make a variant of the boomshine game in javascript and everything works when I draw a circular shape with the arc function. However when i try to replace the arc function with the drawImage function to use a coin image instead of a circular shape I start having problems when I clear the canvas to delete the previous drawn circular shapes. If I don't clear the canvas before rendering the images, the images are drawn on the canvas except the old images are still on the canvas. But when i do clear the canvas before rendering the images again, nothing is drawn on the canvas.

I have included screenshots, the links are below.

This is how I clear the canvas:

```
var ctx = game.context;
ctx.fillStyle = "darkgray";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, game.canvas.width, game.canvas.height);
```

This is how i draw the image:

```
function drawImageBall(x,y,radius,startAngle,color)
{
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'img/coin-icon.png';

var tmpCtx= game.context;
var ax = x-radius;
var ay = y-radius;

img.onload = function() {
    tmpCtx.save();
    tmpCtx.beginPath();
    tmpCtx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    tmpCtx.closePath();
    tmpCtx.clip();

    tmpCtx.drawImage(img, ax, ay, img.width, img.height);

    tmpCtx.beginPath();
    tmpCtx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    tmpCtx.clip();
    tmpCtx.closePath();
    tmpCtx.restore();
};
}
```

[Clearing canvas (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS3pT.png)
[Without clearing canvas (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzb4V.png)

Comment: I don't know if we have enough of your source to figure it out. I actually wrote a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brianmfear/295a1836/) just as a proof of concept; the only thing I tweaked was the starting angle to simulate the arc drawing, so there's nothing fundamentally wrong with the code you've posted. Apologies for the flickering, I was just trying to get something out there.

Comment: You are drawing the image only on the loading of the image, not each call to `drawImageBall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that downloading the `img` will take some time.

During that downloading time, Javascript does not stop(!). Instead JS will continue executing any following code. This is causing your unexpected problems.

So **download the img just once at the start of your app**. That way your `drawImage` will be done in the order that you expect because there will be no delay while your image is downloading.

Comment: I added the image to my global game object and now it works!

Comment: @FerreTahon. Glad you got it sorted. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, I maked some changes, I removed the tmpTcx.clip(), look the fidlle. Tip: For performace questions you don't need load the image every time that you want write the canvas.

Poor Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wf4z0d2h/1/

```
function clearCanvas(){
        var ctx = game.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = "darkgray";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, game.canvas.width, game.canvas.height);
    }

    function drawImageBall(x,y,radius,startAngle,color)
    {
        if(x == undefined){x = 100;}
        if(y == undefined){y = 100;}
        if(radius == undefined){radius = 40;}

        //var img = document.createElement('img');
        //img.src = 'img/coin-icon.png';
        //img.src = "http://ps2.lansa.com/images/icons/normal/256/coin_256.png";

        var tmpCtx= game.context;
        var ax = x-radius;
        var ay = y-radius;


        //img.onload = function() {
            tmpCtx.save();
            tmpCtx.beginPath();
            tmpCtx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            tmpCtx.stroke(); // Draw it
            tmpCtx.closePath();
            //tmpCtx.clip();


            tmpCtx.drawImage(img, ax, ay, img.width, img.height);

            //tmpCtx.beginPath();
            //tmpCtx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ////tmpCtx.clip();
            //tmpCtx.stroke(); // Draw it
            //tmpCtx.closePath();
            //tmpCtx.restore();
        //};
    }
    var img = document.createElement('img');
        //img.src = 'img/coin-icon.png';
        img.src = "http://ps2.lansa.com/images/icons/normal/256/coin_256.png";

    //drawImageBall();
    img.onload = function(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        x = x+10;
        y = y+10;
        clearCanvas();
        drawImageBall(x,y);

    },300);
    }
```